# Linking HTML views file to function in controller

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails

I have a HTML file that I'd like to use in the path:  "app/views/user_mailer/email.html.erb"

I'd like to link that HTML file to the POST request here:

```
RestClient.post "url",
  :html => # path to HTML should go here?
```

I feel like this is a relatively simple task but adding in the path didn't seem to work.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Do You want to render that file from the Controller?

Comment: No I'm merely including it as part of the POST request body

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you're sending the file as a multipart post, from the README (https://github.com/rest-client/rest-client):

```
path = Rails.root.join('app/views/user_mailer/email.html.erb')
RestClient.post "url", :html => File.new(path, 'rb')
```

To send the text in the body:

```
RestClient.post "url", :html => IO.read(path)
```

And if you are trying to render the erb, you'll need to process it as well:

```
require 'erb'
html = ERB.new(IO.read path).result(binding)
```